# how call function in domain Ono2many field odoo 8

Tags: odoo

message Error:

> TypeError: old_api() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)

**code py:**

```
@api.model
def domain_users(self):
        if self.env.user.login=="bendjeddou.o":
            domain=[('exp_P','>',0)]
        else:
            domain=[]
        return domain
o2m_materiels fields.One2many('gmat.journaleline','rapJor_ids',string='Materiel',domain=domain_users)
```

**class py:**

```
class Journaleline(models.Model):
    _name = 'gmat.journaleline'
    _description    =   'Detail materiel'

   rapJor_ids = fields.Many2one('gmat.rapporjournal',string='num')
   exp_P = fields.Float(string='Panne(H)',default=0)
```

Comment: You should post the complete error message, including the traceback and file/line number information. As it is, the error message you report concerns a function named `old_api`, which isn't in the code you've shown us.

Answer (score 0):

all message error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


    File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 544, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 581, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 317, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 314, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 810, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 410, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 944, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3148, in read
    result = BaseModel.read(records, fields, load=load)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3183, in read
    self._read_from_database(stored, inherited)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3370, in _read_from_database
    res2 = self._columns[f].get(cr, self._model, ids, f, user, context=context, values=result)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 773, in get
    domain = self._domain(obj) if callable(self._domain) else self._domain
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

TypeError: old_api() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)

Comment: remove this answer when you need to add something to your question you can edit it directlty

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
# remove the decorator
def domain_users(self):
        domain = False
        if self.env.user.login=="bendjeddou.o":
            domain=[('exp_P','>',0)]
        else:
            domain=[]
        return domain

o2m_materiels = fields.One2many('gmat.journaleline',
                                'rapJor_ids',
                                string='Materiel',
                                domain=lambda self: self.domain_users())
```

or for less typing

```py
# no need to define method
o2m_materiels = fields.One2many('gmat.journaleline',
                        'rapJor_ids',
                        string='Materiel',
                        domain = lambda self:  self.env.user.login == "bendjedou.o" and [('exp_P','>',0)] or [])
```

**EDITS:**
ok for some reason i think the signature of the method 
must be in old api try this:

```py
    # or this
    # def domain_users(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    def domain_users(self, cr, uid, context=None):
            domain = False
            user = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context).
            if user.login == "bendjeddou.o":
                domain=[('exp_P','>',0)]
            else:
                domain=[]
            return domain


    o2m_materiels = fields.One2many('gmat.journaleline',
                                    'rapJor_ids',
                                    string='Materiel',
                                    domain=domain_users)
```

May because your model is created using `osv.Model` not `model.Model`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160719/discussion-on-answer-by-tchi-odoo-how-call-function-in-domain-ono2many-field-odo).

Comment: like this error after update code:  ParseError: "ValidateError
Champ(s)  `arch` en erreur vis \xe0 vis de la contrainte : Invalid view definition   D\xe9tails de l'erreur : domain_users() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)  " while parsing /opt/odoo/addons/app_MATERIELS/views/rapportJournal.xml:34, near
<record id="gmat_view_rapportjournalier_graph" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">gmat.rapportJournal.graph</field><field name="model">gmat.rapporjournal</field><field name="arch" type="xml"> <graph string="graph Panne par projet" default_order="date_rj">

Comment: follwing messag : <field name="date_rj" string="Date"/></graph> </field></record>

Comment: sorry Chourar couldn't help you hope you find the problem